embedded Browser automation with selenium within desktop app
I am working with a desktop application that has an embedded Chromium browser. I am using Selenium and C# to interact with the application. While I can successfully interact with Win32 and WPF controls on the screen, I am unable to interact with elements within the embedded browser. Selenium does not seem to recognize the controls on the desktop screen when the application switches to the embedded browser view. How can I enable Selenium to interact with elements inside the embedded Chromium browser? Are there any specific drivers, configurations, or workarounds I should consider?
I dont have a URL, it automatically get opens within application and create a tree on further controls which have frameworkID=chrome
